# Can we add domain inside server action in odoo 15

Tags: odoo-15

I want to show server action only on some filtered data. suppose I have a list with status='pending','done'. Now I want to show 'done server action' only if data is filtered as 'pending'. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: How you did you create the unfiltered action?

Comment: it's a clue? https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/using-ir-actions-server-i-have-create-a-server-action-i-need-to-restrict-depend-on-user-group-permission-60173

Comment: Because filtering the current page view doesn t imply to reload the page (not server side), you should handle this using javascript/jquery (client side)